# How do you write a 'not in' select statement in Joomla 2.5 SQL?

Tags: joomla

Please explain how to write the commented out line in Joomla in the query below.

I can't figure it out using the [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase); that has only the simplest of queries.

```
function getUsersFromDatabase()
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
    $query = $db -> getQuery(true);     
    $query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('u.id', 'u.name', 'u.username', 'u.email')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__users', 'u'))         

    //->where($db->quoteName('u.id') . ' not in (select m.user_id from ' . $db->quoteName('#__user_usergroup_map', 'm') .' where ' . $db->quoteName('m.group_id') . ' in (4,19))') //no admins or superusers        

    ->order($db->quoteName('u.name') . ' ASC');     
    $db ->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db -> loadObjectList();  
    return $result;         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Joomla's restrictive SQL querying platform to query your database. You can do the following:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "YOUR SQL QUERY";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Major extension, including K2, use the above straightforward method (they don't use Joomla's restrictive SQL).

Comment: How does this handle the Joomla table prefix that changes on each server and is handled by the normal code using #__ ?  (E.g. one server is fkj3f_users and another is gqp3l_users)

Comment: You can use #__ - it'll work. For example, $sql can be "Select * FROM #__content";

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

There is some alternate options like below,

```
$query
    ->select('*')
    ->from('products')
    ->where('category = ' . $db->q('catA'))
    ;
$q2
    ->select('*')
    ->from('products')
    ->where('category = ' . $db->q('catB'))
    ;
$query->union($q2);
$products = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList();
```

There is some performance boostup with Joomla3.x using `union`. and it have some restriction over [Joomla older versions](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_union_methods_in_database_queries).

Hope it helps..